# ActiveAdmin - how to find the id of the default scope?

Tags: activeadmin

How can I find the id of the default scope in ActiveAdmin?

eg:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  scope :foo, default: true
  scope :bar
  controller do
    def my_method
      id_of_default_scope = ??? # do something that returns :foo
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what is `id` of `default_scope`??

Comment: My question is: what do I put on the right-hand-side of "id_of_default_scope = "?